# compute similarity measure between 2 strings

Tags: java, string, string-comparison

I have two strings that I have splited them to words and for each pair of words in two strings.

I have the similarity between them.

How to compute the final similarity between two strings?

Comment: `Arrays.equals` probably

Comment: I should explain my question, I have two string like this:
String1: EnableAdvertResult
String2:AdvertisementDel
Then I have splited them like this:
X[0]=Enable
X[1]=Advert
X[2]=Result
Y[0]=Advertisement
Y[1]=Del
And then compute similarity between each pair elements, like this:
sim(x[0],y[0])=a, sim(x[0],y[1])=b, sim(x[1],y[0])=c, sim(x[1],y[1])=d, sim(x[2],y[0])=e, sim(x[2],y[1])=f

Now I want to know that, what is the best way to compute similarity between string1 and string2 according to above sim?